# Converting array to Linked list - from Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list

It is one of the challenge in the book I fail to understand, or my brain is unable to break it down. Here is the solution function:

```
 function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

so we are looping the array inversly so first time list should be:

```
list = {value:20, rest:{value:20, rest:**mind blows here**}}
```

can any one help me through this process?

Answer (score 16):

reducer can be used to create linked list from array elements.

```js
function ListNode(val, next) {
  this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
  this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next)
}

let input = [1, 2, 3];


let head = input.reverse().reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc == null) {
    acc = new ListNode(curr);

  } else {
    acc = new ListNode(curr, acc);
  }
  return acc;
}, null);

console.log(head);
```

Comment: I love this. You can even shorten it: `array.reduce((acc, curr) => new ListNode(curr, acc), null)`

Comment: Great answer. But `reverse` is kinda unnecessary. [Reduce Right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) would be more effiecent and shorter here.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is:

```
function L(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
}

//We have to develop
/*
L{
    val:1,
    next:{
        val:2,
        next: {
            val:3,
            next: {
                val:4,
                next:null
            }
        }
    }
}
*/

function createL(a){
    let node, temp;
    for(let i=a.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(!node)
            node = new L(a[i]);
        else {
            temp = new L(a[i]);
            temp.next = node;
            node = temp;
        }
    }
    return node;
}

createL([1,2,3,4]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just step through it, keeping track of the values of each name/variable as you go:

Initially:

```
array = [10, 20]
list = null
i = 1
```

Next step:

```
array = [10, 20]
list = {value: 20, rest: null}
i = 1
```

Next step:

```
array = [10, 20]
list = {value: 20, rest: null}
i = 0
```

Next step:

```
array = [10, 20]
list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
i = 0
```

At this point the loop, and the function, ends.

The key is *when* operations are performed.  Since this is [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) style programming (as opposed to [(pure) functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)), the value associated with a name (variable) can be changed during the execution of the code.  So when `list` is read and when `list` is assigned a new value is crucial.

Comment: what will be the output of this: `console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]));`
When I am executing this, I get: `{ value: 10,
  rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: [Object] } } }`. Where are the remaining nodes??

Comment: They are there.  Your browser's console limited the amount of output it displayed.  You can interactively inspect your object right there in the console and see all of it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach will be to create a dummy node. Then, push each array element into the dummy node. Then return the dummy node's next node.

```
class ListNode {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data
        this.next = null                
    }
}

const arr = [1,2,3];

let dummy = new ListNode(-1);
let dummyHead = dummy;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  dummyHead.next = new ListNode(arr[i]);
  dummyHead = dummyHead.next;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you did step by step ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create an object that has inside 2 elements. first element is the value, the second element is the rest of the list. in the line `list = {value:20, rest:{value:20, rest:list}}` we are basically creating the list from end to start, so you always add the list former status. so let's say we had 3 elements [10,20,30].
1. we start in 30 - creating an object called list with the elements value = 30, list = null.
2. we are in 20 - taking the list object that looks like this {value:30, rest:null} and placing it inside of a new object with the 20 value, so we have `{value: 20, rest:{**old list** --> {value:30, list:null} }}`
now we change the reference of list to point to the newly created object.
`list = {value: 20, rest:{**old list** --> {value:30, list:null} }}`
3. we do the same as in 2.

now you have a list. (hope I was clear)

Answer (score 0):

With some extra logs

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(i); //2, then 1
    console.log(array[i]); //20, then 10
    list = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: list //null, then {value:20, rest: null}
    };
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
//{ value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: null } }
```

you can see that although you are iterating through the list in reverse, the `list` object's `value` property will be the last iterated array element. The `rest` property will be a copy of `list` at that iteration.

Answer (score 0):

update [hasan.in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63599046/11138616) answer in 2022.I like that, and it can be shorter and more direct.

```js
function ListNode(val, next) {
  this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
  this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
}

const arrToList = (arr) => arr.reduceRight((last, val)=> last = last === null ? new ListNode(val) : new ListNode(val, last),null)

const arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(arrToList(arr))
// {val: 1, next: {val: 2, next: { val: 3, next:  null}}}
```

typescript version

```
class ListNode {
  val: number
  next: ListNode | null
  constructor(val?: number, next?: ListNode | null) {
    this.val = val === undefined ? 0 : val
    this.next = next === undefined ? null : next
  }
}

const arrToList = (arr:number[]) => arr.reduceRight<null|ListNode>((last, val)=> last = last === null ? new ListNode(val) : new ListNode(val, last),null)

const arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(arrToList(arr))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).